# New Ingress block for each ip address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

My AWS security group, deployed with Terraform, has a `cidr_blocks` argument with about 20 IP's.

```
ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port = 443
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["x", "y", "z"...]
    description = ""
    security_groups = ["c", "v", "b"...]
  }
```

Now, I want each of these IP's to sit in an individual ingress block, as I have to add different descriptions to them. While I could make a new ingress block for each IP/security group I have, that would be a gigantic mess. Is there a prettier way to do this in Terraform?

**Update 1**

Would this work?

```
locals {
 ips = ["x","y","z"]
 descriptions = ["x", "y", "z"]
}

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = local.ips
    content {
      from_port = 443
      to_port = 443
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = local.ips
      description = local.descriptions
    }
  }
```

Will this create 3 ingress rules - IP x + description x, IP y + description y, ..?

**Update 2**

This is the output

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on secgroups.tf line 36, in resource "aws_security_group" "alb":
│   36:       cidr_blocks = ingress.value.ips
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is "x.x.x.x/x"
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
```

**Final Update**

Solved it by doing:

```
locals {
ips = {
 "x" = "x"
 "y" = "y"
 "z" = "z"
 }
}

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = local.ips
    content {
      from_port = 443
      to_port = 443
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = [ingress.key]
      description = ingress.value
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Answer (score -1):

```
locals {
ips = {
 "x" = "x"
 "y" = "y"
 "z" = "z"
 }
}

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = local.ips
    content {
      from_port = 443
      to_port = 443
      protocol = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = [ingress.key]
      description = ingress.value
    }
  }
```